# Send already filled form with Python Requests

Tags: python, forms, submit, python-requests

just a quick question.

Is there a way to submit a pre-filled form with the Python Requests library?

For example, I'm on a page with a pre-filled form, there is a 'Submit' button that's gonna submit a post request with data which is already in form. Is there a way to 'simulate' clicking the 'Submit' button?

I'd like to get the Form Data upon the submission (from header) instead of scrapping each field and getting it's value.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Most likely, just clicking the "submit" won't be enough; you'll have to actually submit all the form fields also.

Comment: basically what I needed is something like select["#form_id"].submit(). I will check if the `Beautiful soup` package can cover it, and if it can't - I'll use the `robobrowser` package that, hopefully, can do it based on it's documentation (suggested by @alecxe below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things like these can easily and transparently be solved with packages like [`MechanicalSoup`](https://github.com/hickford/MechanicalSoup) or [`RoboBrowser`](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser). Both are based on `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`, they can read the contents of a form and perform "submit" using the default/given or the custom/supplied values.

[`mechanize`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/) is an another, probably a more popular alternative for this task.

Comment: Thank you very much @alecxe, I don't really like to use 3rd party solutions that combine a few libraries, I'd rather prefer to use the plain libs they consist of :) Actually, BeautifulSoup seems very interesting and will probably help me to solve the described problem. Will post my solution if it's gonna work for me. But again - it's basically a scraping method...

Comment: @AntonTerem well, you can, of course, extract each field with `bs4`, but I was driven by  "I'd like to get the Form Data upon the submission (from header) instead of scrapping each field and getting it's value." when answering the question. Note that you would still have access to `BeautifulSoup` instance when using `robobrowser` or `mechanicalsoup`. Thanks.

Comment: You convinced me to use the `robobrowser` package, seems like the most popular solution with a good documentation. Will be back with a feedback soon. Thank you again.